# How to implement a variable for an array (Angular 4)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get the right value for the skill.team[*variable here*].name where Angular gets all the team name from the skill

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="skill.teams[1].name" name="teamName" id="teamName" class="form-control">
                    <option *ngFor="let skill of skills" [value]="skill.teams[1].name">{{ skill.teams[1].name }}</option>
                  </select>
```

**ARRAY**

```
skill = {
  _id:'',
  name:'',
  teams:[{name:'team1'},{name:'team2'}]
}
```

Comment: It's Angular. There's no such thing as AngularJS 4.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're looking for; you should be iterating over the `skill.teams` array with your `*ngFor`. This also changes the model to be `skill.name`, however, which may or may not be exactly what you're looking for.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="skill.name" name="teamName" id="teamName" class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let team of skill.teams" [value]="team.name">{{team.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a console log for skill `console.log(skill);` the console output will give you the structure of your iterables.